# How long should a 4-5 pound rib roast take in an infrared cooker?

Tags: beef, grilling, cooking-time, roast

I'm going to attempt to cook a 4-5 pound rib roast in an infrared cooker. Specifically, a Big Easy Infrared Turkey Fryer.

Everything I've read says that it's done when it's done. I understand the sentiment there, but I would like to know an approximate time so that I can have other foods prepared to hit the table at the same time.

How do I estimate how long this will take?

Comment: If the manufacturer's information doesn't provide  you the information you need you may just have to get a meat thermometer and monitor the internal temp and practice once or twice.. what a terrible thing to have to do. Will you need help eating the 'extra' roast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the recipe they have on their site for [pork shoulder](http://www.charbroil.com/Recipe/8x11-print.aspx?RecipeID=809) as a guideline, since it's very similar in terms of size and shape to a beef roast (just not as heavy).

They estimate 10 minutes per pound, which is more or less consistent with the per-side estimate of most broiler recipes (which is very similar to infrared cooking).

So start with an estimate of 40-50 minutes but do what they recommend and monitor the temperature very carefully.

I have to point out that 4-5 pounds is very heavy/large for high-heat cooking methods like broiling or grilling (or infrared); it's not the same as infrared "frying" a turkey or a leg of lamb which has a very high surface area/weight ratio. Steaks would no doubt come out great this way but larger roasts respond better to *roasting*, so don't be too surprised if your roast starts to get seriously charred on the outside before it's sufficiently cooked on the inside.

You might want to consider starting with smaller, 2-3 lb roasts, and move up the weight next time if those come out perfectly. Based on their claims, it should take roughly the same amount of time for one large item vs. two smaller items anyway.

Comment: So, I have one roast. Would you recommend cutting it into two roasts and cook them simultaneously?

Comment: @basilard99: I'm not sure what the inside of one of these devices looks like; if it's wide enough to fit them both side-by-side, or if you can cook them simultaneously on two racks or something, or physically separate them so they're actually exposed to the heat separately, then I guess that would be fine. If they're just going to be stacked on top of each other then no, that won't help at all.

Comment: For those who come across this thread, I cooked the roast as the recipe stated. It came out fairly nice, but I believe that it was a bit tough due to not cooking low enough. I think a better cut of meat also would have helped.

Comment: @basilard99 did you end up cutting it in half or doing it as one roast? how long (approx) did it take.

Answer (score 0):

I have cooked 2 other roasts before and you can learn from my mistakes but believe me when I tell you, it will be the greatest piece of meat you'll ever eat, it turns out better than restaurant bought, for a 6lb chuck of meat get a thermometer and remove it 15 degrees before rare cuz it will continue to cook and it should be cooked at low heat so it will take minimum hour and a half, keep pouring the drippings over the meat every 20 minutes and you'll love the out come